# How to plot the values without covering with each other?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 11 values for each x-axis. In here, I will simplify my data to only 4 values each. However, they are too close so it's hard to see each length of the error bar (So messy!). I'm thinking of plot the values paralled, but it may not work because of the numbers in x-axis are `string`, not **int**. Is there any way to solve it? I appreciate it

My current code is like

```
row_name = ['6', '7', '9', '10']
figure(num=None, figsize=(12,8), dpi=400, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

#ee and duration is a dataframe and I create randomly here
ee = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
duration = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(4, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
e = ee.rename(columns={x:y for x,y in zip(ee.columns,range(0,len(ee.columns)))})
dur = duration.rename(columns={x:y for x,y in zip(duration.columns,range(0,len(duration.columns)))})

for i in range(4): 
    plt.errorbar(row_name, dur[i], yerr = e[i], capsize=4,fmt = 'o')
```

And the result would be something like this
[image]

But my expected description is like
[image]

Comment: I don't know why you ended up with the data structure you present here. It is, mhm, interesting. Maybe you can create a combined dataframe instead in long form, then you could use [seaborn's pointplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html?highlight=pointplot#seaborn.pointplot) with `dodge=True`.

Comment: @Mr.T, I tried it just, but even not working.

Answer (score 1):

Add some `jitter` along the x-axis to prevent overprint.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


row_name = ["6-piece", "7-dogs", "9-cats", "10-sloths"]
fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(12, 8), dpi=400, facecolor="w", edgecolor="k")

# ee and duration is a dataframe and I create randomly here
ee = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(4, 4)), columns=list("ABCD"))
duration = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(4, 4)), columns=list("ABCD"))
e = ee.rename(columns={x: y for x, y in zip(ee.columns, range(0, len(ee.columns)))})
dur = duration.rename(
    columns={x: y for x, y in zip(duration.columns, range(0, len(duration.columns)))}
)

for i in range(4):
    # add jitter -0.125, 0.0, ...
    jitter = (-1 + i) * 0.125
    # extract first number from string
    row = [int(re.findall("\d+", x)[0]) + jitter for x in row_name]
    plt.errorbar(row, dur[i], yerr=e[i], capsize=4, fmt="o")

# set your labels
fig.axes[0].set_xticks(row, labels=row_name)
```

**Output:**
[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for answering! But my x-axis is a string name in every scale, like "6-piece", "7-dogs"..., so it can't convert to int.

Comment: @Megan Updated my solution.

Comment: Hey, thanks again! How if I want the label name to be ["6-piece", "7-dogs", "9-cats", "10-sloths"], not "custom_label"? If I take away the last two lines, it shows [6,7,8,9,10] again

Comment: @Megan Updated my solution.